# What's the right flag if a link has malware

Tags: discussion, flagging, hyperlinks

I flagged an obvious spammer whose site was blacklisted by google for malware. Its straightforward since it *is* spam on the other hand What would be the proper action if a legitimate user posts a link, and its unwittingly malware?

Flag it? Edit it? Comment that its malware and leave it as is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For spam with a malicious link, flag as spam and vote to delete if you can. Usually I'm against editing spam posts, but if it is a likely malicious link it certainly makes sense. The spam flag is important as it auto-deletes after 6 flags.

For a legitimate user just remove the link and comment, there is likely no need to delete the post.

Comment: spam flag *also* results in a auto rep drop. I'd rather use a custom flag there if I'm convinced its a legit user.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The question is about an obvious spammer, in the case of an accidental bad link editing out is enough

Comment: We usually discourage editing out the link as keeping it in the post (even when deleted) helps tracking abuse, whereas you could never find the URL later through search when it was removed from the last revision. Adding a warning notice might be more adequate.